# Video Tags No Longer Available Via YouTube API?

Tags: tags, youtube, youtube-api, keyword

About a month ago YouTube decided to get rid of it's "tags" from the frontend of their website:
http://youtubecreator.blogspot.com/2012/08/tags-removed-from-video-watch-pages.html

Which also in turn left **media:keywords** blank through any API feed request as read here:
http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/video-tags-just-for-uploaders.html

The nice thing was for another month or so (until a few days ago) you could still access a video's "tags" or "keywords" through the API by looping through the **category term**(s)

It seems YouTube has taken that away also and it now only displays ONE category term for each API feed...and most of the time they are the basic YouTube categories like "Music" or "People" etc.

My questions to the YouTube development team is why was this taken away from the API (I understand taking it away from the frontend of the website) and will it ever return in any form to the API?

---

In the original Creators blog post you guys stated:

"*Tags remain an important way to organize and help others find your videos. We strongly encourage you to continue tagging videos -- this will help increase your audience by improving the discoverability of your content.*"

So if Tags are still important and still utilized for search results...why in the world are they not available through the API anymore?

---

Any help and/or info would be greatly appreciated as this has completely destroyed the functionality of MANY of my sites! Thank you.

Comment: Why are you asking for YouTube technical support here?

Comment: ummmm..because this is where their official API help is now located: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow.html why do you care???

Comment: I did not realize that.  On the surface, this didn't seem a question appropriate here, but I've learned something new :)

Comment: I just found out now :( Thanks for starting this thread! interested if there's any alternatives now.

Comment: Freebase seems a good alternative.

Answer (score 3):

It appears they've made them private and you must use an authorized API request with adequate channel privileges to access them now.  This really sucks since I've used them for filtering videos from a channel on a site and making authorized connections to the API via PHP has been complicated for me to get working correctly.
And the fact that this added complication is ONLY for keywords seems a bit ridiculous, but I don't guess the Youtube API team cares.

Unless a WHOLE lot of people complain about it, I doubt they'll add this back as a public.

Comment: hmmm that's interesting that they are still available through the authorized API..I will have to look into that. Thanks! But yeah I'm with you nothing will change because only a small number of people even know it's happened.

Answer (score 1):

I just added

> Update: This change also applies to <category
>   scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat"> tags,
>   which were not mentioned in the original announcement.

to the [announcement blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/video-tags-just-for-uploaders.html). <category> tags should have been removed for the same reason <media:keywords> was removed, but due to an oversight they were left in unauthenticated API responses for a few weeks. There are no plans to add back keyword information via either metadata field.

Comment: arrgghhh...unfortunately not what I wanted to hear :/ This was very crucial for auto linking recent posts of mine to specific Twitter accounts based on specific tags coming in from the API. I just don't quite understand why these we're taken away from the API when it was really only the frontend you guys we're concerned about (or at least that's what we were told)

Comment: Do you know of ANY possible workaround? Tags are an integral part of how the internet works..just look at this very site for a great example of that. I completely understand removing them from the frontend where most people abused them..but removing them from the API doesn't make sense to me. Can you please help me understand? Thanks for your time Jeff!

Comment: There's no "workaround", _per se_, because making this change was an intentional product decision. (If there were a workaround, it would be turned off as well.)

Comment: @JeffPosnick, does this mean that it's not possible to add tags to live-stream created through the YouTube API?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have some semantics in the video, Freebase Topics can help. You can for instance do a JSONp call

```
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic${item}?filter=/type/object/name&callback=putFBname"></script>
```

with a small javascript function

```
<script>
function putFBname(respuesta){
 span=document.getElementById(respuesta["id"]);
 span.innerHTML=" "+respuesta["property"]["/type/object/name"]["values"][0]["text"];
}
</script>
```

to get the name of the topic.

Freebase topics come in the API v3.